# How to link to forked package in distutils, without breaking pip freeze?

Tags: python, pip, distutils

**Preface**
The official python package `python-openid` (as distributed through pypi.org) does not work with Google Apps. Somebody wrote a fix to this and uploaded [the patched source](http://github.com/Bouke/python-openid/tags) to github. Now I want to create a package which should link to this forked package.

Now when installing this package, everything is well. The forked package is installed and everything is fine. However, when doing a `pip freeze`, there is no mentioning of where the package came from. As the forked package should be used, including the official package breaks deployments. How can I link to a forked package in my own package and also list the forked package in `pip freeze`?

**Update**

Ok, so I created the tag `2.2.5-bouke0`, created a distribution and uploaded it to [github](http://github.com/Bouke/python-openid/downloads). My `setup.py` of the referencing package now looks like this:

```
dependency_links=[
    'http://github.com/Bouke/python-openid/downloads',
],
install_requires=[
    'python-openid == 2.2.5-bouke0',
],
```

When building and installing this package everything is fine. The referenced package is downloaded from github and installed correctly. However, `pip freeze` does not show where the package came from:

```
django-federated-login==0.1.3
python-openid==2.2.5-bouke0
```

As the version `2.2.5-bouke0` cannot be found on pypi, the deployment of such a `requirements.txt` will fail. How can I instruct `pip freeze` to reference the alternative source from where to get the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a tag `2.2.5` in the repository.

Put `-f https://github.com/adieu/python-openid/downloads` into the `requirements.txt` file.

To be sure, change version number to something like `2.2.5-bouke1`. Read semver.org for details.

Comment: Ah; the `--find-links` directive should be included in the requirements file so that pip will also look for downloads at that url. More info on [requirements file format](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html#indexes-find-links).

Comment: By the way, you can do the same with `-r` option, to get some kind of inheritance for your requirements files. For example, usually I create `requirements/base.txt`, `requirements/production.txt` and `requirements/development.txt`. And last two have `-r base.txt` at the first line.