# How to state in requirements.txt a direct github source

Tags: python, github, pip, requirements.txt

I've installed a library using the command

```
pip install git+git://github.com/mozilla/elasticutils.git
```

which installs it directly from a Github repository.  This works fine and I want to have that dependency in my `requirements.txt`.  I've looked at other tickets like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024607/how-to-link-to-forked-package-in-distutils-without-breaking-pip-freeze) but that didn't solve my problem.  If I put something like

```
-f git+git://github.com/mozilla/elasticutils.git
elasticutils==0.7.dev
```

in the `requirements.txt` file, a `pip install -r requirements.txt` results in the following output:

```
Downloading/unpacking elasticutils==0.7.dev (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement elasticutils==0.7.dev (from -r requirements.txt (line 20)) (from versions: )
No distributions matching the version for elasticutils==0.7.dev (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
```

The [documentation of the requirements file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format) does not mention links using the `git+git` protocol specifier, so maybe this is just not supported.

Does anybody have a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 998, accepted):

Normally your `requirements.txt` file would look something like this:

```
package-one==1.9.4
package-two==3.7.1
package-three==1.0.1
...
```

To specify a Github repo, you do not need the `package-name==` convention.

The examples below update `package-two` using a GitHub repo. The text after `@` denotes the specifics of the package.

#### Specify commit hash (`41b95ec` in the context of updated `requirements.txt`):

```
package-one==1.9.4
package-two @ git+https://github.com/owner/repo@41b95ec
package-three==1.0.1
```

#### Specify branch name (`main`):

```
package-two @ git+https://github.com/owner/repo@main
```

#### Specify tag (`0.1`):

```
package-two @ git+https://github.com/owner/repo@0.1
```

#### Specify release (`3.7.1`):

```
package-two @ git+https://github.com/owner/repo@releases/tag/v3.7.1
```

Note that in certain versions of pip you will need to update the package version in the package's `setup.py`, or pip will assume the requirement is already satisfied and not install the new version. For instance, if you have `1.2.1` installed, and want to fork this package with your own version, you could use the above technique in your `requirements.txt` and then update `setup.py` to `1.2.1.1`.

See also the [pip documentation on VCS support](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/).

Comment: Out of all the other answers, I can't believe *none* of them just showed a requirements file with a blend of "normal" reqs with a git one thrown in for comparison. I was so thrown off by what looked like command-line (`-e`) options. Thanks for showing a blend of both so I could put this in context!

Comment: Pointing to the release `3.7.1` with `git+git://github.com/path/to/package-two@releases/tag/v3.7.1#egg=package-two` did not work for me. What worked for me was `git+git://github.com/path/to/package-two@3.7.1#egg=package-two`.

Comment: This answer was very helpful. One thing though. Those `git+git://...` notation somehow caused ssh-relative errors on my Linux box. So I ended up switching them to `git+https://...` notation and then they work perfectly.

Comment: I wasn't sure if you should what to put for `egg=<package name>`. I forked a project where the package name that you `pip install` has a dash in it (`package-two`), but the module you import has an underscore in it (`package_two`). I used the name of the imported module (with the underscore) and it works fine.

Comment: [GitHub dropped support](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/) for the git protocol -- you'll have to use https.

Comment: @MikeTwo updated - does the new version look correct to you?

Comment: Excelent answere. It helps me a lot!

Comment: I think you may also need `setup.py` or `pyproject.toml`.

Comment: What if I want to install something that isn't in the root of a repo? Like if a repo has many folders with many packages how can I install any individual package?

Comment: @wsams you are correct that for certain recent versions of pip you will need to update `setup.py` - updated the answer.

Comment: Does `#egg=package-two` still work in 2023? I had to use `package-two @ git+https:...` instead to get it working for my project, specifically in GitHub Actions.

Comment: @someone I think you're correct, updating the answer for latest pip versions.

Comment: @YPCrumble I suggest you add an example where the root of the Python project is in a sub-directory of the git repository.

Comment: Would it be possible to invent a version number as an option somehow or do we need to change the version in the git repo? See this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77204995/how-to-specify-version-of-module-installed-from-git-repo-with-pip-install-r-req/77206404

Answer (score 392):

[“Editable” packages syntax](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#install-editable) can be used in `requirements.txt` to import packages from a variety of [VCS (git, hg, bzr, svn)](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.1/requirements.html#version-control):

```
-e git://github.com/mozilla/elasticutils.git#egg=elasticutils
```

Also, it is possible to point to particular commit:

```
-e git://github.com/mozilla/elasticutils.git@000b14389171a9f0d7d713466b32bc649b0bed8e#egg=elasticutils
```

Comment: I didn't manage to checkout locally such an editable version (due to syntax problems, probably) and so ended up using the `git+git` variant (which worked).  In the `requirements.txt` your version works, so thank you very much :)

Comment: The `docs` link was not working for me; I've used [an older one](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/1.1/requirements.html).

Comment: What I did not understand is that the syntax showed is exactly what goes in requirements, i.e. there is no package name before the -e.

Comment: Adding "-e" isn't necessary depending on whether you want the package to be in editable mode, see answer by @qff .

Comment: In OpenShift Online Next Gen Developer Preview, build throws error:  `AssertionError: Sorry, 'git://github.com/Username/repo-name.git#egg=repo-name' is a malformed VCS url. The format is <vcs>+<protocol>://<url>, e.g. svn+http://myrepo/svn/MyApp#egg=MyApp`

Comment: What to do in case of using --src option in requirements.txt? I am trying:
`--src ./myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages -e git+https://github.com/Remak-a-s/rmkGoogleAPIs.git#egg=rmkgoogleapi` and it said:
`pip: error: no such option: --src`

Comment: Shouldn't it be **`-e git+git://`** instead of `-e git://`? I got a *"should either be a path to a local project or a VCS url beginning with svn+, git+, hg+, or bzr+"* error message.

Comment: i get this `Could not detect requirement name, please specify one with #egg=`

Comment: @zhukovgreen you should include `--src path/to/env/site-packages` in command: `pip install -r requirements.txt --src ...`

Comment: Looks like this will be deprecated soon: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7554. Looks like the correct way to do this is now:
-e git+ssh://git@github.com:path/to/your/repo (use https or http (insecure) if you don't have ssh set up)

Comment: Why this random chunk of code without context is upvoted and accepted I can't understand.

Comment: What is the "-e" meaning?

Answer (score 211):

`requirements.txt` allows the following ways of specifying a dependency on a package in a git repository as of pip 7.0:<sup>1</sup>

```
[-e] git+git://git.myproject.org/SomeProject#egg=SomeProject
[-e] git+https://git.myproject.org/SomeProject#egg=SomeProject
[-e] git+ssh://git.myproject.org/SomeProject#egg=SomeProject
-e git+git@git.myproject.org:SomeProject#egg=SomeProject (deprecated as of Jan 2020)
```

For Github that means you can do (notice the omitted `-e`):

```
git+git://github.com/mozilla/elasticutils.git#egg=elasticutils
```

**Why the extra answer?**
I got somewhat confused by the `-e` flag in the other answers so here's my clarification:

The `-e` or `--editable` flag means that the package is installed in `<venv path>/src/SomeProject` and thus not in the deeply buried `<venv path>/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/SomeProject` it would otherwise be placed in.<sup>2</sup>

**Documentation**

- <sup>1</sup> https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git
- <sup>2</sup> https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support

Comment: But note that if you omit the `-e` your next `pip freeze` may not give the correct results for this package

Comment: Note: `git+git@` urls [are deprecated](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7554) since [Jan 2020](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/7543). The others are still supported.

Comment: syntax for ssh is `git+ssh://git@git.myproject.org/SomeProject#egg=SomeProject`

Answer (score 103):

First, install with `git+git` or `git+https`, in any way you know. Example of installing `kronok`'s branch of the `brabeion` project:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/kronok/brabeion.git@12efe6aa06b85ae5ff725d3033e38f624e0a616f#egg=brabeion
```

Second, use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to get the right thing in your `requirements.txt`. In this case, you will get

```
-e git+https://github.com/kronok/brabeion.git@12efe6aa06b85ae5ff725d3033e38f624e0a616f#egg=brabeion-master
```

Third, test the result:

```
pip uninstall brabeion
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: pip freeze still list the package i use as a closed, anterior version. and not a direct github checkout

Comment: You need to use `-e' option for 'pip freeze' to generate an url

Comment: pip 9.0.1: `no such option: -e`

Comment: You mean `git+https`? In the text you say `git+git` and in the code `git+https`

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins fixed.

Comment: This method at least allowed me to find out the correct syntax for Bitbucket. For example, if my package name is "fred", I can use this scheme:

`pip install -e git+ssh://bitbucket.org/mybitbucketaccount/fred.git@397783bc10d5b13c7d5078d4368402aabcd05fb8#egg=fred`

Answer (score 26):

Since pip `v1.5`, (released Jan 1 2014: [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/develop/CHANGES.txt), [PR](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/1215)) you may also specify a subdirectory of a git repo to contain your module.  The syntax looks like this:

```
pip install -e git+https://git.repo/some_repo.git#egg=my_subdir_pkg&subdirectory=my_subdir_pkg # install a python package from a repo subdirectory
```

Note: As a pip module author, ideally you'd probably want to publish your module in it's own top-level repo if you can. Yet this feature is helpful for some pre-existing repos that contain python modules in subdirectories.  You might be forced to install them this way if they are not published to pypi too.

Answer (score 17):

Github has zip endpoints that in my opinion are preferable to using the git protocol. The advantages are:

- You don't have to specify `#egg=<project name>`
- Git doesn't need to be installed in your environment, which is nice for containerized environments
- It works much better with [pip hashing](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools#using-hashes) and caching
- The URL structure is easier to remember and more discoverable

You usually want requirements.txt entries to look like this, e.g. without the `-e` prefix:

```
https://github.com/org/package/archive/1a58aa586efd4bca37f2cfb9d9348958986aab6c.tar.gz
```

To install from main branch:

```
https://github.com/org/package/archive/main.tar.gz
```

There is also an equivalent `.zip` endpoint, but it was reported in a comment that always using the `.tar.gz` endpoint avoids problems with unicode package names.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment of this similar [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24811490/943773), the zip extractor can have issues with unicode package names. Specifying `.tar.gz` instead of `.zip` will fix this.

Comment: @ryanjdillon I updated the answer to recommend `.tar.gz` instead of `.zip`.

Comment: This is the one answer I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: The only circumstance where you don't have to specify `egg=package` is when the package has a proper name, and only one package, that pip will find and translate. That is never safe to assume. The compressed file provided by github doesn't change that, the repositories you tested would work the same with the git+https hyperlink or the zip "endpoint".

Answer (score 17):

None of these answers worked for me. The only thing that worked was:

```
git+https://github.com/path_to_my_project.git
```

No "e", no double "git" and no previous installs necessary.

Comment: The -e means that the package will be installed as an editable package, this may or may not be desirable depending on the package and how you will use it.

Answer (score 8):

It seems like this is also a valid format:

```
gym-tictactoe @ git+https://github.com/haje01/gym-tictactoe.git@84e22fc28fe192ba0040bdd56a697f63d3d4a3d5
```

If you do a `pip install "git+https://github.com/haje01/gym-tictactoe.git"`, then look at what got installed by running `pip freeze`, you will see the package described in this format and can copy and paste into requirements.txt.

Comment: This fixes my issue from the `private repo` and `setup.py` `install_requires` options. Thanks!

Comment: Just needed this today, and the solutions in older answers did not work for me, but this one worked well. I wonder if there was a change in pip? In particular, the `#egg=gym-tictactoe` at the end failed, but `gym-tictactoe @ ` at the beginning worked, with the same `git+https:...` URL either way.

Comment: This is the syntax for non editable package (without the -e option)

Answer (score 5):

I'm finding that it's kind of tricky to get pip3 (v9.0.1, as installed by Ubuntu 18.04's package manager) to actually install the thing I tell it to install. I'm posting this answer to save anyone's time who runs into this problem.

Putting this into a requirements.txt file failed:

```
git+git://github.com/myname/myrepo.git@my-branch#egg=eggname
```

By "failed" I mean that while it downloaded the code from Git, it ended up installing the original version of the code, as found on PyPi, instead of the code in the repo on that branch.

However, installing the commmit instead of the branch name works:

```
git+git://github.com/myname/myrepo.git@d27d07c9e862feb939e56d0df19d5733ea7b4f4d#egg=eggname
```

Comment: Are you sure your branch is also remote?

Comment: It wasn't pointing to a local copy, if that's what you're wondering.

Comment: This syntax is now deprecated, for github public repositories it's now `git+https` and for private repositories it's `git+ssh`

Comment: @IuriGuilherme Can you give an example of the use of `git+ssh`? I tried `pip install git+ssh://git@github.com:user/repo.git` but then it for some reason adds **** and tries `git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet 'ssh://****@github.com:user/repo.git' 'C:\Users\userame\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-x2x6s19c'` which gives me 

      `ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:user: Name or service not known
      fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

      Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.`

Comment: @Adriaan the syntax is `pip install 'git+ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git'` or the full version `pip install 'git+ssh://git@somewebsite.com/someoneusername/somerepositoryname.git@1234567890abcdef#egg=packagename'` (I included the quotes for shell escaping)

Answer (score 4):

For private repositories, I found that these two work fine for me:

```
pip install https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/owner/repo/archive/main.tar.gz
```

Where `main.tar.gz` refers to the `main` branch of your repo and can be replaced with other branch names. For more information and using the more recent Github API see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#download-a-repository-archive-tar):

```
pip install https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@api.github.com/repos/owner/repo/tarball/master
```

If you have git installed and available, then

```
pip install git+https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/owner/repo.git@main
```

achieves the same, and it also allows for some more flexibility by appending `@branch` or `@tag` or `@commit-hash`. That approach, however, actually *clones* the repo into a local temp folder which can take a noticeable amount of time.

You can use the URLs in your requirements.txt, too.

Comment: For private repositories there's the `git+ssh` specification, the authentication is handled with the ssh program in the same shell