# Is django-piston compatible with Django 1.6.5?

Tags: python, django, pip, django-piston

We are using `django-piston==0.2.3` with `Django 1.4.12`. We want to upgrade Django to `1.6.5.` I tried to upgrade first to `Django 1.5.8`, but it's not compatible with piston 0.2.3. Is there a way to use Django 1.6.5 with piston? I noticed there is a fork, but how do we install the fork with `pip install`? We have a requirements file which is installed automatically with `pip install -r requirements.txt`, is it possible to use the fork in the requirements file? And why is the original piston not updated?

Answer (score 1):

I have found this issue on the BitBucket's official django-piston repository:
https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/issue/235/attributeerror-wsgirequest-object-has-no#comment-7147190

It's about an incompatibility with Django 1.6 and the issue is still marked as 'new' so, although I haven't found any official statement, that would mean that **the latest version of django-piston is not compatible with Django 1.6**.

Regarding the installation of a github fork with `pip install`, you can find an example with GitHub on this other thread:
[How to state in requirements.txt a direct github source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source)

I think it can be easily extended to the case of `hg` if that is the case of the django-piston's fork you are referring to.

Hope this helps