# Django 1.8: How do I use my first 3rd Party Fork with my current project?

Tags: python, django, django-apps

I'm still very new to development...

I would like to simplify [django-friendship](https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship/) and add some different functionality. I've forked it on GitHub. I'm not sure what to do next.

Where should the local copy of my `django-friendship` repo go?
Should I integrate it into my current Django project as an app, or set it up as a separate project? In which case, how do I set my main Django project to use it as an app while developing it?

Any guidance or other resources I can learn from here would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How are the dependencies for your project created? Are you running in a `virtualenv`? You could add that specific GitHub repo to your `requirements.txt` and install the forked version rather than the original (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/16584552/3001761), or add the fork as a `submodule`.

Comment: I'm not using virtualenv - I know I should, but I'm only working on the one project and it's just me. If I work with anyone else I'll move to a virtual env in vagrant. Submodule sounds good, but I'm using BitBucket w/SourceTree for my project, and the `django-friendship` fork is on github. Can I still do that?

Comment: As long as your project is still using `git` (BitBucket also supports `hg`, in which case I doubt it's even possible) I think that should be fine. Give it a go and see what happens!

Answer (score 13):

There's a few options open to you:

### Install directly from Github

Add the following (replace with your forked repository) to a `requirements.txt` file or install directly with `pip install`:

> git+git://github.com/revsys/django-friendship.git#egg=django-friendship

This will download a copy of your repository into your python environment. If you make changes to the repository however, you'll need to reinstall this every time you push changes.

### Download a local copy and install

This method is much cleaner:

```
// Clone the repository locally
git clone https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship.git

// cd into the project folder
cd django-friendship

// Install the package into your python environment
// The `-e` tells pip this package is editable
pip install -e .
```

The project is now linked directly. You can now work on the forked repository locally and the changes will be available to your app straight away.

In your `requirements.txt` file you'll want to add the following for deployment later:

> git+git://github.com/revsys/django-friendship.git#egg=django-friendship

Take a look at the docs for [pip](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.1/requirements.html) for more information on dependency management.

Comment: As the project has a `setup.py` you could also use `python setup.py develop` in the second example (i.e. replacing `pip install -e`).