# How to change dependency from name to github link?

Tags: python, git, pip

I have a problem with installing things through pip. I have a `requirements.txt` file with a position from github like:

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/packages/my-package.git@master#egg=my-package-0.1.1
```

I run command `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Repository is cloning but there is a dependency that should be cloned also through github link, but internal search is trying to get in just by name and it reply that:
`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement...`
`No matching distribution found for needed-package <2.0.0,>=1.1.0` 
Is it possible to replace name of this package by github link?
In my requirements.txt I have only one link: to main repository.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to state in requirements.txt a direct github source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source)

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're asking. Does one of your dependencies (defined in your `requirements.txt`) have its own faulty dependency (defined in _its_ `requirements.txt`)?

Comment: In my dependencies from `requirements.txt` I have one direct link to github. After cloning this repo it starts collecting some additional things (I think that some requirements of this repo itself). But this fails. It can not find package by name. This package is also private github repository so I am looking for a way to make pip looking for this repo throug github link instead of package name.

Answer (score 0):

example from my requirements on real project:

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/PreppyLLC-opensource/django-allauth.git#egg=django-allauth
```