# How to use `pip` and setup.py to automatically install dependencies that may be private repositories hosted on github

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, packaging, setup.py

I don't think this is a dupicate, because I tried all links I could find for the past 2 hours and none of the solutions worked. I want the user to be able to clone a repository, `cd` into the directory, and run `$ pip install .` (or at least `pip install --process-dependency-links .`)  to install the package, its pypi dependencies **AND** its (latest) **private** github dependencies assuming the user has read permissions for them. (also the devs should be able to run `$ pip install -e .`)

my `setup.py`:

```
setup (
    ...
    install_requires=['
        ...
        private-pkg
        ...
    ],
    dependency_links=[
        'git+ssh://git@github.com/private-org/private-pkg.git@master#egg=private-pkg'],
    )
```

I also tried different variations for dependency_links:

- `https://github.com/private-org/private-pkg/tarball/master#egg=private-pkg`
- `git+https://git@github.com/private-org/private-pkg.git@master#egg=private-pkg`

I also tried adding a trailing `-1.0.0` (for version) and it doesn't work but in any case, I'd like the user to be able to install the lastest version

Note that I can do:

`pip install "git+https://github.com/private-org/private-pkg"` and it works fine, but I can't get `pip install .` to work no matter what.

All these fail with the same error:

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement private-pkg (from my-pkg==1.0.0) (form versions: ) No matching distribution found for private-pkg (from my-pkg==1.0.0)`

Running it with `pip install -vvv .` shows that `pip` never looks for the git link, but running it with `pip install --process-dependency-links -vvv .` tries to fetch it but fails for various reasons ("Cannot look at git URL", or "Could not fetch URL"). Note that `--process-dependency-links` is marked as deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

pip expects to have a link to index page (such as PyPI) in `dependency_links`. Any link to VCS is going to be skipped. This behavior was changed in commit [26facdd](https://github.com/pypa/pip/commit/26facddaa81be3447b8e06a9886c03b90fd68309).

I recommend to define all external dependencies in `requirements.txt` file and then run `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Example of requirements.txt:

```
foo>=1.0
-e git+ssh://git@github.com/private-org/private-pkg.git@master#egg=private-pkg
```

See also [How to state in requirements.txt a direct github source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source)

There is an article about [setup.py vs requirements.txt](https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/#a-setuptools-misfeature), which describes this misfeature.