# What is the syntax for using ampersand in a Pip requirements file e.g from a Git url?

Tags: python, git, pip, requirements.txt

What is the right syntax to use `&` inside a requirements.txt? Is there an escape sequence?

I have a Python package in a subdirectory of a Git repo. I can install the package successfully using pip (syntax here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26174655/6032073)

However, I cannot install if I put the Git URL into a requirements.txt file. I believe it is breaking on the ampersand character in the URL (&subdirectory=blah)

Quotes dont work inside the requirements file. Escaping the ampersand with backslash and carot does not work either (`\&` or `^&`).

```
$ pip install 'git+ssh://git@github.example.com/reponame.git@branchname#egg=packagename&subdirectory=one/two'
[OK]

$ cat requirements.txt
"git+ssh://git@github.example.com/reponame.git@branchname#egg=pac..."

$ pip install -r requirements.txt 
RequirementParseError: Missing distribution spec "git+ssh://git@github.example.com/reponame.git@branchname#egg=packagename&subdirectory=one/two"
```

Update

- I got it to work using the `-e` syntax in requirements.txt (no quotes needed). Is this possible without `-e`?

Comment: How about not quoting the target repository?