# Private python packages install with dependecies

Tags: python, dependencies, package, pypi

We want to start using our own python packages in a central distributed way.
The requirement is to have someone commit a new change and the other developers
will pull or update in some way once. After that they will run setup.py develop/install to have the new changes.
We want to implement it in a way that when updating the code or installing one package it will install it's dependencies as well (could be from two repos: public pypi and private packages).

There are two ways I've seen to do that:

1. Github - using dependency_links for other repos.
   The problem is this feature is depricated and can't be used even while specifying
   process-dependency-links.
2. Creating our own PyPiCloud server and implementing everything from scratch.

Is there a way to still use github for our requirement?
Can't I install a package with it's dependencies (which are also private packages)?
If there are other options would love to hear about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this solution: [How to state in requirements.txt a direct github source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source)?

Answer (score 0):

> pip supports installing from Git, Mercurial, Subversion and Bazaar,
>   and detects the type of VCS using url prefixes: "git+", "hg+", "bzr+",
>   "svn+".

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#git