# How can I use git repos as dependencies for my PyPi package?

Tags: python, git, pip, pypi

I have a package which I'm pushing to PyPi and some of the depedencies are not packages, but installable git repositories. My `requirements.txt` looks like this

```
sphinx_bootstrap_theme>=0.6.5
matplotlib>=2.2.0
numpy>=1.15.0
sphinx>=1.7.5
sphinx-argparse>=0.2.2
tensorboardX
tqdm>=4.24.0
Cython>=0.28.5

# git repos
git+git://github.com/themightyoarfish/svcca-gpu.git
```

Accordingly, my `setup.py` has this content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup
import setuptools
import os

with open('requirements.txt', mode='r') as f:
    requirements = f.read()
    required_pkgs, required_repos = requirements.split('# git repos')
    required_pkgs = required_pkgs.split()
    required_repos = required_repos.split()

with open('README.md') as f:
    readme = f.read()

setup(name=...
      ...
      packages=setuptools.find_packages('.', include=[...]),
      install_requires=required_pkgs,
      dependency_links=required_repos,
      zip_safe=False,   # don't install egg, but source
)
```

But running `pip install <package>` does not actually install the git dependency. I assume that `pip` doesn't actually use the setup script. It works when I run `python setup.py install` manually.

**Edit**:

I also tried removing `dependency_links` and just using `install_requires` with the repository, but when installing my repository from GitHub (the project including the above files), I'm met with

```
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
error in ikkuna setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or 
list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Invalid requirement, parse error at "'+git://g'"
```

It has been suggested in other answers that one can put something like

```
git+https://github.com/themightyoarfish/svcca-gpu.git#egg=svcca
```

into `requirements.txt`, but that fails with

```
   error in <pkg> setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Invalid requirement, parse error at "'+https:/'
```

**Question: (How) Can I list git repositories as dependencies for a pip package?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to state in requirements.txt a direct github source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source)

Comment: The linked question and top answers do not seem to solve the problem because it deals with requirements files, but not with `pip`. The idea is having to state the requirement in a way that `setup()` understands it.

Comment: I should have made it clearer in the question that `requirements.txt` is merely a proxy for `setuptools` dependencies in this case.

Answer (score 14):

Out of the 50 or so different ways to specify git dependencies for Pip, the only one that did what I intended was this one (outline in PEP 508):

```
svcca @ git+ssh://git@github.com/themightyoarfish/svcca-gpu
```

This can be used in `install_requires`, which solves the issue of `dependency_links` being ignored by pip.

An amusing side-effect is that the package cannot be uploaded to PyPi with such a dependency:

```
HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Invalid value for requires_dist. Error: Can't have direct dependency: 'svcca @ git+ssh://git@github.com/themightyoarfish/svcca-gpu' for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
```

Comment: I am stuck on " Error: Can't have direct dependency:" issue and not sure how to solve it :-(

Comment: "Don't use PyPi" is the only solution until they change this.

Comment: I *had to* release a package to PyPi. So I ended up releasing two packages: first, the direct dependency, and then releasing my actual package after converting direct dependency to regular dependency!

Comment: Ran into the same problem with pypdfium2 ([issue 177](https://github.com/pypdfium2-team/pypdfium2/issues/177)). Not so amusing after all.

Answer (score 1):

We tried it with `pyproject.toml` and it didn't work for us either.

```py
requires = [
    "geci_plots @ git+https://github.com/IslasGECI/geci_plots.git@v0.4.0",
    "lmfit",
    "pandasql",
    "scikit-learn==1.1.3",
]
```

It seems that direct references don't allow it.

```bash
ERROR    HTTPError: 400 Bad Request from https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/        
         Invalid value for requires_dist. Error: Can't have direct dependency:  
         'geci_plots @ git+https://github.com/IslasGECI/geci_plots.git@v0.4.0'
```

I assume the direct references are the GitHub repos.

Answer (score 0):

According to the next post related to [How to state in requirements.txt a direct github source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source).
You could add a **package** from git remote repository with the next syntax:

```
-e git://github.com/themightyoarfish/svcca-gpu.git
```

Reference:
 [Install a project](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/?highlight=e#cmdoption-e) in editable mode (i.e. setuptools “develop mode”) from a local project path or a VCS url with`-e`

Comment: I don't want to use editable mode, but it doesn't seem to work without `-e`.

Comment: See edited question; this does not work because `install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers;`, which apparently that is not.

Comment: Hi oarfish! I really recommend you follow the next structure created by kennethreitz.
On this repository you will see how to create an awesome [Setup.py](https://github.com/kennethreitz/setup.py)

Comment: Maybe, you should split a break space, something like that: `required_pkgs = required_pkgs.splitlines()` [Reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/3uzl2a/setuppy_requirementstxt_or_a_combination/)

Comment: I really don't see how your linked `setup.py` file deals with non-pypi packages at all.

Comment: No, it was just in order to improve and standarize your setup.py file.