# Build a python package with two independent modules where one is a git subodule

Tags: python, pypi, python-packaging, python-poetry

I am trying to build a Python package for distribution that contains two independent modules (`lkh` and `tsplib95`), but with a non-standard directory layout.

The two modules are contained in different repos ([pylkh](https://github.com/ben-hudson/pylkh) and [tsplib95](https://github.com/ben-hudson/tsplib95)), and both have the standard layout. However, I want to distribute them together.

**How can I build this package?**

- I can use any build system, so long as it produces a package that can be published to PyPi.
- I *can't* change the file/directory structure of [tsplib95](https://github.com/ben-hudson/tsplib95) (it is a fork of another repo that I want to keep synced).
- I *can* change the directory structure of [pylkh](https://github.com/ben-hudson/pylkh).
- I don't want to include `tsplib95` as a submodule of `lkh`. I would like to have them both as top-level packages.
- I would like to avoid multi-step builds.

## Where I'm at

The (current) directory structure is:

```
pylkh
├── pyproject.toml
├── lkh
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── ...
└── tsplib95 (git submodule)
    ├── setup.py
    └── tsplib95
        ├── __init__.py
        └── ...
```

pyproject.toml is (based on the [Poetry docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#packages)):

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "lkh"
...
packages = [
    { include = "lkh" },
    { include = "tsplib95/*.py", from="tsplib95"},
]

...

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

This builds a package with the following structure:

```
lkh-x.x.x.tar.gz
├── LICENSE.txt
├── lkh
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── ...
├── PKG-INFO
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
└── tsplib95
    └── tsplib95
        ├── __init__.py
        └── ...
```

*However*, this does not import `tsplib95` properly because there is an extra subdirectory.

## Edit

- Add module names to make the question easier to understand.

Comment: I see that `module2-repo` has a `setup.py` file. Is `module2-repo` its own [distribution package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Distribution-Package)? If I understand you correctly, you're trying to re-export the import packages from `module2-repo` as import packages of the new distribution? While ignoring the `setup.py` already in `module2-repo`?

Comment: Sidenote: it may be helpful if you [edit] your question to give your example distribution(s) and import package(s) different names. Otherwise it can get confusing whether name is being used to refer to one vs the other.

Comment: Added the module names like you suggested. Yes, it's okay if we ignore the setup.py in `module2-repo` (`tsplib95`) and just merge that into the top level `pyproject.toml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to expose both `module1` and `module2` as [import packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package) packages in your new [distribution package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Distribution-Package), you can use the configuration

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "my-distribution"
# ...
packages = [
    { include = "module1" },
    { include = "module2", from="module2-repo" },
]
```

After installing your distribution, both `module1` and `module2` will be importable.

Do note that this ignores any distribution metadata (e.g. the `setup.py` file) that exists in `module2-repo`.

Comment: I tried this, but I still get an extra subdirectory (i.e. `tsplib95/tsplib95` - same as I showed in the question) which causes `tsplib95` to not import correctly.

Comment: @beenjaminnn Maybe update your version of poetry... this works perfectly for me. Wheel from `poetry build`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OheO.png

Comment: yup... you're right 

Answer (score 0):

#### Use a `git` dependecy instead

Since `module2-repo` appears to already be a distribution package (given that it contains a top-level `setup.py` file, it's possible that what you really want to is declare `module2-repo` as a dependency of your new distribution.

If that's the case, you can simply list `module2-repo` as a [git requirement](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#git-dependencies):

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
module2-distribution = { git = "https://git.example.com/module2-repo.git", rev = "abcd1234" }
```

This way, when your new distribution gets installed, `module2-repo` will be automatically retrieved and installed using its *own build backend*, and will it retain its own distribution metadata.

---

#### Warning against `path` dependencies

You may be tempted to use a "hybrid" approach where you include `module2-repo` as a git submodule, and then declare it as a [path dependency](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#path-dependencies) like

```ini
module2-distribution = { path = "./module2-repo-submodule" }
```

This works, *provided* that you always uses distributions on the same machine as they are built on. It will break if you ever attempt build your distribution (e.g., as an sdist or wheel) on one machine and then use that built distribution on a different machine. This is because during the build process, path dependencies are resolved to *absolute paths*. The path dependency above will be resolved to something like `/home/user/some/specific/path/my-project/module2-repo-submodule`, which almost certainly won't exist on a different system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried that but I can't seem to upload a package with a git dependency to PyPi. I get the error: `Invalid value for requires_dist. Error: Can't have direct dependency: 'tsplib95 @ git+https://github.com/ben-hudson/tsplib95@7634ca0' `

Comment: Seems it's not allowed, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54894359/2426888)