# Sharing projects with external Python libraries

Tags: python, virtualenv

How can I share a project (through Github) with someone when my project is using multiple personal modules/packages?

Using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` is obviously not enough, because there is no place to download packages I created specifically for this project.

Is pushing the contents of the project in my repository as a virtual environment viable solution?

What if I also need to have an older version of Python (3.6.5) for example?

Ty,

Comment: `pip freeze` is the conventional approach, what's wrong with it?  I also don't understand your "there is no place to download external packages from" comment

Comment: I meant packages not on PyPi etc - modules I made specifically for the project I'm trying to share.

Comment: sorry, I misinterpreted your question!  you can edit the text file to point to your own repositories, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/16584552/1358308

Answer (score 0):

What these "personal modules/packages" are? The only reason to make a separate package is reusability.

If you do not plan to use it somewhere else, then just include them as modules in your project.

If you plan to use it somewhere else but don't think it could help somebody else then make a package and push it to to Github/Gitlab/Bitbucket/etc. It's possible to install dependencies from there using pip.

If you plan to use it somewhere else and want to share your work with all the python community - deploy package on PyPI.