# How to specify a specific github repo version in requirements.txt?

Tags: python, setup.py, requirements.txt

I want to be able to install a specific version of a github repo. I followed the instructions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source) and my file `requirements.txt` looks as follows:

```
git://github.com/twoolie/NBT@f9e892e
```

I also tried the following versions:

```
git+git://github.com/twoolie/NBT@f9e892e
git+git://github.com/twoolie/NBT.git@f9e892e
git://github.com/twoolie/NBT.git@f9e892e
```

but in every case when I try to install the actual package, which requires the repository `NBT` from commit hash f9e892e, I get the error message

```
error in PyBlock setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Invalid requirement, parse error at "'://githu'"
```

So how to do it correctly?

Comment: I've tried putting `git+git://github.com/twoolie/NBT@f9e892` in a `requirements.txt` file and it works. Are you sure that this is the thing that causes your error?

Comment: When I put e.g. `NBT==1.5.0` in the `requirements.txt` file it works fine. When I put the string you suggest, I get the same error as before.

Comment: If I put only that line it works so maybe it could be an error on the package that depends on NBT and not NBT itself.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by adding the following argument to the `setup` method in `setup.py':

```
install_requires=['NBT@git+git://github.com/twoolie/NBT@f9e892'],
```

and using an empty `requirements.txt` file. With these setting the install of the specific version of the package did work finally.