# How to create a conda environment file without local development packages?

Tags: pip, conda

I have a conda environment with packages installed via `conda install`. I also have two local development packages that were each installed with `pip install -e .`. Now, `conda env export` shows everything, including both local development packages. However, I don't want conda to include them when creating the same environment on other machines - I want to keep doing it via `pip install -e .`.

**So how can I exclude both local packages when creating the environment.yml file? Do I need to manually remove them or is there a way to this from the command line?**

Comment: Remove the offending lines from the YAML. Though, recognize that you can run `pip install -e` commands *through* the YAML (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/59864744/570918)

Comment: Oh I didn't know that! Either way requires manually editing the environment.yml file, but at least with the latter I won't need to  run `pip install -e .`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are some alternative flags for `conda env export` that change output behavior (e.g., `--from-history` is most notable), there really isn't anything as specific as OP describes. Instead, manually remove the offending lines.

Note that YAMLs do support all `pip install` commands, so the editable installs can also be included. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/59864744/570918.

### Consider Prioritizing the YAML Specification

In a software engineering setting, I would expect that users should not even be hitting development environments with `conda install` or `pip install` commands. Instead, the team should have a maunally-written, version-controlled YAML to begin with and all installations/changes to the environment are managed *through editing the YAML file* and using `conda env update` to propagate changes in the YAML to the environment.

That is, `conda env export` should not be necessary because the environment already has a well-defined means of creation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I have a follow-up question: how do you find out which package version works (is compatible) with the rest of the environment? For example, let's say that I want to add numpy to an existing environment. Would you simply add `- numpy` to your yaml file (without version number), propagate the changes to your environment, see which numpy version conda ended up choosing (say, `numpy=1.19.2`) and then updating your entry in the yaml file with this version?

Comment: @olamarre yeah, that's almost exactly what I do. I'll add a new package to the YAML first without any constraint, solve the whole environment (using `mamba`), inspect the solved version, and then specify [up-through minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64594513/570918) (so `numpy=1.19` in your example). However, it depends on your purpose - I'm mostly developing Snakemake components these days where I want reproducibility. Someone developing a library for reuse might be more concerned with identifying a minimal version to support and use `>=` specifications.