# Python - replace specific file in module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

When someone installs my github repo. I'd like it to install specific files that override files from another module. There's a public library, but there are a couple bugs we want to fix, and the creator doesn't want to merge in a pull request.

I could copy the ENTIRE library into our repo, and that does work. But that seems cumbersome for 5 lines of changes in 2 files.

Is there any easy way to replace specific module files with a different version when my github repo gets installed? If I delete anything but the changed files, I get import errors.

Ideally, the user would install the public library, install our project, and the bugfixes would be implemented (at least when running scripts from our project..)

Comment: You could try making a wrapper that calls all the functions from the public library, but defines new functions over the ones that don’t work. The feasibility of that would vary, though.

Comment: How about forking & fixing the repo and then using the link to the fixed repo as github source in the requirements file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source

Comment: Fork and Submodule would be helpful. Or monkey patching.

Comment: what do you mean by "fork and submodule" how would that work?