# How to add a Spacy model to a requirements.txt file?

Tags: python, git, heroku, spacy

I have an app that uses the Spacy model "en_core_web_sm". I have tested the app on my local machine and it works fine.

However when I deploy it to Heroku, it gives me this error:

"Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory."

My requirements file contains spacy==2.2.4.

I have been doing some research on this error and found that the model needs to be downloaded separately using this command:
`python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

I have been looking for ways to add the same to my requirements.txt file but haven't been able to find one that works!

I tried this as well - added the below to the requirements file:

`-e git://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm==2.2.0`

but it gave this error:

"Cloning git://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0.tar.gz to /app/.heroku/src/en-core-web-sm

Running command git clone -q git://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0.tar.gz /app/.heroku/src/en-core-web-sm
fatal: remote error:
           explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0.tar.gz is not a valid repository name"

Is there a way to get this Spacy model to load from the requirements file? Or any other fix that is possible?

Thank you.

Comment: You're getting that error because that's an URL to a zip file... You need to pass an URL to a repository for git to be able to clone it...

Comment: Thanks Swetank, I'm not able to figure out what that url would be. Would you be able to help please? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: The answer below has been edited to answer your question! :D

Comment: Thanks Swetank, the edited answer still gives an error: " Cloning git://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz to /tmp/pip-req-build-at911nv7 Running command git clone -q git://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz /tmp/pip-req-build-at911nv7 fatal: remote error: explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz is not a valid repository name"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so after some more Googling and hunting for a solution, I found this solution that worked:

I downloaded the tarball from the url that @tausif shared in his answer, to my local system.

Saved it in the directory which had my requirements.txt file.

Then I added this line to my requirements.txt file: `./en_core_web_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz`

Proceeded with deploying to Heroku - it succeeded and the app works perfectly now.

Comment: check edit of my answer, that may be more cleaner way to do it if works.

Comment: Thank you so much Tausif, will test the latest edit to your answer  in my next edit of the app and will revert here accordingly.

Answer (score 28):

Add this in your deployment step, if using docker add in Dockerfile

```
pip3 install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz --user
```

> EDIT

Add

`spacy>=2.2.0,<3.0.0
https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm`

in `requirements.txt`

[Spacy Doc](https://spacy.io/usage/models)
Refer `Downloading and requiring model dependencies` section

For more detail on how to add *github-source* [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source) and follow **YPCrumble** answer

Comment: Thanks Tausif, is there a way I can add this to the requirements file? I'm not using docker.

Comment: Thanks Tausif, it still gives an error: "
         Cloning git://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz to /tmp/pip-req-build-at911nv7
         Running command git clone -q git://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz /tmp/pip-req-build-at911nv7
         fatal: remote error:
           explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz is not a valid repository name"

Answer (score 14):

For en-core-web-sm == 3.0.0, this worked for me.

Replace the line `"en-core-web-sm==3.0.0"` with

```
en-core-web-sm @ https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: this is the accepted answer, works 100%