# Cloud Function Package won't download

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a little (big) problem that I can't solve , I tried to find a solution to it but I can't get anything. Maybe you will see it better than me. it seems it can't import a package, Here is the error :

```
Build failed: `pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fr-core-news-md==2.2.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 38)) (from versions: none)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for fr-core-news-md==2.2.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 38))
    
    error: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1; Error ID: D670E3AB
```

my `main.py` file:

```
import fr_core_news_md
```

my `requirements.txt`:

```
fr-core-news-md==2.2.5
```

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a Spacy model to a requirements.txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61702357/how-to-add-a-spacy-model-to-a-requirements-txt-file)

Comment: Sorry for the delay , Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions is failing to install the `fr-core-news-md` dependency because there is no `fr-core-news-md` on PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/fr-core-news-md/