# how to prevent IPTCInfo3 from creating a copy of the original after saving keywords?

Tags: iptc

I use IPTCInfo3 in my Python app to write keywords to the IPCT metadata of an image.
For some reason if I use `info.save()` it creates a copy of the original, e.g. it will write the keyword to Clean.JPG but will also create Clean.JPG~ without the keywords.

If I use `info.save_as('Clean.jpg')` instead (try to force it to overwrite the original), it doesn't write the keywords to the file.
Is there a solution to this?

```
import iptcinfo3

new_keyword = ["cool", "sad", "blah"]
info = iptcinfo3.IPTCInfo('C:/Tmp/IPTCINFO/Clean.JPG')
for keyword in new_keyword:
    if keyword.encode('UTF-8') not in info['keywords']:
        info['keywords'].append(keyword)
info.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me.

You will have to comment out 2 lines in the iptcinfo3.py file inside the
"save_as" method around line 695 of the file.

```
else:
    tmpfh.close()
    #if os.path.exists(newfile):
    #    shutil.move(newfile, newfile + '~')
    shutil.move(tmpfn, newfile)
```

This will write inside the original file without creating a new one and leaving the one with ".jpg~" behind.

Answer (score 0):

The pypi release of [IPTCInfo3](https://pypi.org/project/IPTCInfo3/) is unfortunately not updated, but the [package version on Github](https://github.com/james-see/iptcinfo3) has a merged pull request that [introduces an overwrite option](https://github.com/james-see/iptcinfo3/pull/29).

If you call the `save` method as: `.save(options=["overwrite"])` it overwrites the original file with the new IPTC info and does not leave a `.jpg~` file behind.

You can install the latest package directly from Github using:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/james-see/iptcinfo3.git@master
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35998253/1256347) in case you want to add it to your `requirements.txt` file.