# pip install via requirements.txt specify a direct GitHub private repo + branch name erroring with exit status 128

Tags: python, git, github, pip, requirements.txt

I am trying to add a package to my `requirements.txt` file that is:

- From a private GitHub repo

  - I'm a member of the private repo
  - I have `ssh` configured for the private repo
- From a branch besides `master`, whose name has a slash in it
- Using `ssh` protocol

All over the internet, there are questions on this topic.  Here are the [`pip` docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support) on this:

> `pip install -e "vcs+protocol://repo_url/#egg=pkg&subdirectory=pkg_dir"`

And an answer for GitHub from [How to state in requirements.txt a direct github source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source)

> `git+git://github.com/path/to/package-two@master#egg=package-two`

---

**Attempt Method #1**

I am trying to use this answer in my `requirements.txt` file:

```
-e git+ssh://github.com/Organization/repo-name.git@branch/name#egg=foo
```

I am getting an error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q ssh://github.com/Organization/repo-name.git /path/to/venv/src/foo Check the logs for full command output.
```

And when I view the logs using the `--log` option:

```
Using pip 20.2 from /path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
Non-user install because user site-packages disabled
Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/yl/tnzf__856m90wwx0jrqwmhbw0000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-yysggsvl
Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/yl/tnzf__856m90wwx0jrqwmhbw0000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-ckqzav7i
Initialized build tracking at /private/var/folders/yl/tnzf__856m90wwx0jrqwmhbw0000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-ckqzav7i
Created build tracker: /private/var/folders/yl/tnzf__856m90wwx0jrqwmhbw0000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-ckqzav7i
Entered build tracker: /private/var/folders/yl/tnzf__856m90wwx0jrqwmhbw0000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-ckqzav7i
Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/yl/tnzf__856m90wwx0jrqwmhbw0000gn/T/pip-install-c9xw78wg
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple
Obtaining foo from git+ssh://github.com/Organization/repo-name.git@branch/name#egg=foo (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Cloning ssh://github.com/Organization/repo-name.git (to revision branch/name) to ./venv/src/foo
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q ssh://github.com/Organization/repo-name.git /path/to/venv/src/foo Check the logs for full command output.
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 216, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 182, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 183, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 388, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 326, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    return self.preparer.prepare_editable_requirement(req)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 523, in prepare_editable_requirement
    req.update_editable(not self._download_should_save)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 664, in update_editable
    vcs_backend.obtain(self.source_dir, url=hidden_url)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/vcs/versioncontrol.py", line 641, in obtain
    self.fetch_new(dest, url, rev_options)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/vcs/git.py", line 230, in fetch_new
    self.run_command(make_command('clone', '-q', url, dest))
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/vcs/versioncontrol.py", line 771, in run_command
    return call_subprocess(cmd, cwd,
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/vcs/versioncontrol.py", line 166, in call_subprocess
    raise SubProcessError(exc_msg)
pip._internal.exceptions.SubProcessError: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q ssh://github.com/Organization/repo-name.git /path/to/venv/src/foo Check the logs for full command output.
Removed build tracker: '/private/var/folders/yl/tnzf__856m90wwx0jrqwmhbw0000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-ckqzav7i'
```

---

**Attempt Method #2**

Another way I try for `requirements.txt`:

```
-e git+git@github.com:Organization/repo-name.git#egg=foo
```

The cloning in this actually works!  It also prints this warning: `DEPRECATION: This form of VCS requirement is being deprecated`

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to specify a branch name in this format.

---

**What am I doing wrong?  Am I missing something?**

FYI, my versions:

```
Python==3.8.5
pip==20.2
setuptools==47.1.0
```

Comment: Is it about private repo? I mean in order to clone from a private repo you need the permission i.e. user/pass/private-key  etc

Comment: @LutfarRahmanMilu I updated the question, yes I am a member of the repo

Comment: Kudos on a really well-asked question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured out my problem in both cases... syntax

---

**Attempt #1**

Mistake: needed to say `git@github.com`

Correct method:

```bsh
-e git+ssh://git@github.com/Organization/repo-name.git@branch/name#egg=foo
```

---

**Attempt #2**

Mistake: didn't know one can use `@` twice

Correct method:

```bsh
-e git+git@github.com:Organization/repo-name.git@branch/name#egg=foo
```

Comment: The `-e` is optional with my versions (pip 9.0.1 and git version 2.17.1): without it, the package will be installed into site-packages.  Users may prefer one or the other.

Comment: Just a note, my IDE failed to recognise a dependency as installed when done so with the `-e` flag. Removing that made it work as expected

Answer (score 4):

I run into the same issue and here is how I make it works:

Following the documentation about how to install a private Python package:

- https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/private-python-packages.html#from-a-git-repository

I create a Github token here https://github.com/settings/tokens.

In my `requirements.txt` I added:

```
-e git+https://GITHUB_TOKEN_HERE@github.com/user/repository.git#egg=your_module_name
```

Comment: committing your github token to the `requirements.txt` file sounds like a risky move.