# Which is requirements.txt equivalent to use `-f url` on pip?

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

If I want `pip` to execute `pip install torch==1.6.0+cu92 torchvision==0.7.0+cu92 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html` when using `pip -r requirements.txt`

I've made my `requirements.txt` using `pip list --format=freeze` and it declares torch and torchvision with their versions, but pip has no idea where to get those from.

Is there any syntax I can use, as `git+https://www.github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib.git@e1574a16f0156dd9557fe62a1c5a39e37bd656c6` is for installing a specific version from git?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to state in requirements.txt a direct github source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brequirements.txt%5D+torch