# How to deploy custom python packages to Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, pip, requirements.txt

I am developing a Django app.
I have modified the source code of `daphne` package for my requirements.
But I cant figure out how to use that package in heroku.
Heroku fetches from official site.
Should I publish it to pypi as a separate package?
Thanks for the help

Comment: Try to deploy the app without adding `daphne` into `requirments.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following answer.
Hosting the package in GitHub and accessing it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34518202/15465995