# How to pip freeze source package

Tags: python, python-venv

I am learning how to use venv here: https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#installing-from-source

And it says I can install a source package by:

`python3 -m pip install .`

Which works, but now if I do `pip freeze` then I see:

`my-package @ file:///Users/joesmith/my-package`

The problem is if I export this to a `requirements.txt` and try to install this environment on another machine then it won't work cause the path to source changed obviously.

What is the proper way to use a source package locally like i did but also export it afterwards so that another person can recreate the environment/run the code on another machine?

Comment: Hosting it for example via git is what you need. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35998253/6759844

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pip has support for VCS like git. You can upload your code to git (e.g. Github, Gitlab, ..) for example and then use the requirements.txt. like this:

```
git+http://git.example.com/MyProject#egg=MyProject
```

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#vcs-support

Comment: I need to manually add this line to the requirements.txt? That seems error-prone....

Comment: @guy you can do: `pip install git+http://git.example.com/MyProject#egg=MyProject` and then `pip freeze`. If you can't host it publicly you can add credentials to your git via url if supported (e.g. in github): `git+http://username:password@git.example.com/MyProject#egg=MyProject`

Answer (score 1):

You would install package from PyPI rather than from source.

i.e. `pip install requests`

In this way other developers will also easily run your project.

Comment: I cannot host it publicly. This solution will not work for me.