# How to add PyFeel to my requirements.txt file?

Tags: python, requirements.txt

I'm having a lot of troubles with uploading my currently working React + Flask app to Heroku. I can't push my files on Herkou because of the following error :

```
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyFeel==0.1 (from -r /tmp/build_b4f32723/requirements.txt (line 76)) (from versions: none)
```

PyFeel [https://github.com/AdilZouitine/pyFeel] is installed like this :

```
pip install git+https://github.com/AdilZouitine/pyFeel --upgrade
```

So I don't know how to add it in `requirements.txt`, can someone help me ?

[edit] I tried to add in my `requirements.txt` the following line `git+https://github.com/AdilZouitine/pyFeel --upgrade` but the error is the same

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to state in requirements.txt a direct github source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source)

Comment: @Iguananaut sadly not because on the PyFeel repository there isn't a package or a release so I can't add the .git

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there isn't a "package or release".  There doesn't have to be.  In this case you are installing directly from the git repository itself, and it does have a correct `setup.py`.    I made a `requirements.txt` containing just `git+https://github.com/AdilZouitine/pyFeel` and it works.  Unfortunately it does not appear to correctly specify its dependencies, and it tries to import itself inside its `setup.py` (generally a bad idea unless handled carefully).  So it won't install properly unless you have `numpy` and `nltk` installed *first*.

Comment: There's no need for the `--upgrade` either.

Comment: @Iguananaut do you have any ideas how to force numpy and nltk to be installed before PyFeel using `requirements.txt` ?

Comment: because the owner fixed the `setup.py` but the error remains

Comment: It looks like their fix isn't correct. I'll send them a pull request...