# Install specific release and tag of github repo using requirements.txt

Tags: git, pip, requirements.txt

I want to use requirements.txt to install this specific github package in my project:

https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/tag/en_core_web_sm-3.2.0

but am not sure how to do it. I have tried:

```
git+https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models@releases/tag/en_core_web_sm-3.2.0/v3.2.0#egg=en_core_web_sm-3.2.0
```

but am getting the following error:

```
WARNING: Did not find branch or tag 'releases/tag/en_core_web_sm-3.2.0/v3.2.0', assuming revision or ref.
  Running command git checkout -q releases/tag/en_core_web_sm-3.2.0/v3.2.0
  error: pathspec 'releases/tag/en_core_web_sm-3.2.0/v3.2.0' did not match any file(s) known to git.
WARNING: Discarding git+https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models@releases/tag/en_core_web_sm-3.2.0/v3.2.0#egg=en_core_web_sm-3.2.0. Command errored out with exit status 1: git checkout -q releases/tag/en_core_web_sm-3.2.0/v3.2.0 Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement en-core-web-sm-3-2-0 (unavailable) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for en-core-web-sm-3-2-0 (unavailable)
```

Comment: See here! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source