# How do I install discord 2.0 voice support on requirements.txt?

Tags: python, discord.py

How do I install discord 2.0 voice support on requirements.txt?
Its [Github page](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) says that I need to clone it first and then install it.

But it will not work on requirements.txt.  Any help?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

`discord.py` was not released for a very long time. You can try specifying the git in the requirements according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source).

However, I suggest using a drop-in replacement package called [`py-cord`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/), which achieves the same thing and is regularly released.

Comment: Is it not possible to install the voice support with the official discord.py build?

Comment: It will install an unstable development version. Apart from that, in both cases (on linux systems) you need to install additional packages, something that can't be done via `requirements.txt` but only using a shell script. As a quick reminder, `discord.py` is not an official discord library and is not maintained by discord themselves. I myself have found numerous bugs in `py-cord` but it still seems to be the more maintained version of the library among the two.