# Adding a link to a requirements.txt pip file

Tags: pip, pytorch, python-packaging, requirements.txt

```
pip install torch -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Hey. To fix my torch installation I have to run the above command. I was wondering if I am able to put urls in my requirements.txt?

simply putting the URL inside doesn't seem to work.

I tried the following: `torch @ https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`, but when I go to install i get

```
ERROR: Cannot determine archive format of C:\Users\benn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-eu3abpd_\torch_ef332a557d1f4161bd846ea665b23740
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source

Comment: This is not a github source

Comment: Copy your desired wheel archive link from that web page. An HTML page is not a pip-installable format

Comment: Okay thanks. Was a bit confused since it works when using `pip install -f theLinkhere`

Comment: You can put a `--find-links` option in a `requirements.txt` file, see [the documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#global-options).

Comment: did it work? I am looking to install torch in Azure App Service Virtual environment and it is failing.