# How to specify a `huggingface` model version in the `requirements.tx`

Tags: pip, pipenv, requirements.txt, huggingface

I want to specify a give `huggingface` model version in the `requirements.txt`, say just to give a concrete example, this particular commit.

```
https://huggingface.co/facebook/bart-large-mnli/commit/df7df4d2107d3882675bfd5ad50db1aa8dd7d7be
```

How do I do that? and as a bonus, how do I do that in `pipenv`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35998253/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brequirements.txt%5D+commit

Comment: well, I believe that is for Python packages. A Huggingface model does not seem to have the structure of a python package.

Comment: Then you cannot install it with `pip` or any tool related to `pip` like `pipenv`, `pipx`, `poetry`, etc. All of them can only install Python packages, packed or available on VCS. `requirements.txt` can only lists names of packages, or URLs to packages or VCS with packages.