# Install private Python package with Github personal access token and requirements.txt

Tags: python, docker, github, pip, dockerfile

Normally, I install packages from PyPI by putting them in `requirements.txt` and then running

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Now, when I have a private repo, which is located at Github, I could create a personal access token and run

```
pip install git+https://${GITHUB_PAT}@github.com/<user-name>/<repo-name>.git@<commit hash>
```

However, since I install everything as part of a Dockerfile, I would like to make it possible to install it by just running `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Is that somehow possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70049992

Comment: Thanks for your input. Can I use this with token in a requirements.txt?

Comment: Should be possible, yes. See https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#using-environment-variables