# Specifying GitHub sources in a requirements.txt ile

Tags: github, pip

This is related to the question [How to state in requirements.txt a direct github source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source)

The top-rated answer there has been very helpful in figuring out how to specify GitHub sources in a `requirements.txt` file. The pip documentation is comprehensive and helpful in some areas, but it's lacking in the detail I seek.

The top answer to the above-mentioned question thread gives the following examples:

1. **Specify commit hash**

   `package-two @ git+https://github.com/owner/repo@41b95ec`
2. **Specify branch name (main)**

   `package-two @ git+https://github.com/owner/repo@main`
3. **Specify tag (0.1)**

   `package-two @ git+https://github.com/owner/repo@0.1`
4. **Specify release (3.7.1)**

   `package-two @ git+https://github.com/owner/repo@releases/tag/v3.7.1`

Full disclosure: I am using `git+ssh` everywhere since these are private repos. All of examples work fine for me – with the exception of example **4** (specify release). I'm obviously authenticating just fine.

The reason that example 4 is my preferred choice is that our GitHub Actions workflow builds a Python wheel (`.whl`) file, adding it to the artifacts that reside in the repo's `releases` area.

My hope was that pip would peruse the specified release directory as in the example:

`package-two @ git+https://github.com/owner/repo@releases/tag/v3.7.1`

and detect the wheel file there, downloading it and installing it. Yes, I could use example 3, but this rebuilds the wheel, which is redundant given that a wheel is already built. Honestly, I was hoping that `pip install` would simply grab the latest release from the GitHub release area as it does with wheels packaged on PyPI – but I can't even get this to work pointing to a specific release.

Does anyone have any ideas? If not, I might be pulling out my hair and perusing the pip source code!

Using a `requirements.txt` line formatted as in the example, I get the following errors:

```
  WARNING: Did not find branch or tag 'releases/tag/v0.0.2beta3', assuming revision or ref.
  Running command git checkout -q releases/tag/v0.0.2beta3
  error: pathspec 'releases/tag/v0.0.2beta3' did not match any file(s) known to git
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × git checkout -q releases/tag/v0.0.2beta3 did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

Comment: `pip` and PyPI speak Simple Repository API specified in [PEP 503](https://peps.python.org/pep-0503/) and updated by PEP 592, PEP 629, PEP 658, PEP 691, PEP 700, PEP 708, and PEP 714. GitHub Releases don't speak Simple API. Different languages, different ways to work.